# Has anyone installed MySQLdb for Python on Cygwin?

Tags: python, mysql, cygwin

I'm trying to install MySQLdb for python on Cygwin. Unfortunately, when I run `python setup.py build`, I get the following error:

```
$ python setup.py build
/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/mysql_config: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 16, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "/home/Ben/python/MySQL-python-1.2.2/setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
  File "/home/Ben/python/MySQL-python-1.2.2/setup_posix.py", line 24, in mysql_config
    raise EnvironmentError, "%s not found" % mysql_config.path
EnvironmentError: /usr/local/bin/mysql_config not found
```

Clearly I don't have `mysql_config` installed, which I guess is the problem. This is mentioned in the README for MySQLdb, but it doesn't explain how to either get around it or how to install mysql_config.

So maybe this is as easy as: How can I install `mysql_config` for Cygwin?

Or maybe it's harder than that.

FYI: I have python 2.5.2 and MySQL 5.1.30, running under Cygwin.

Comment: have you installed mysql development packages?

Comment: Ah... No. Do you know where I can get them for cygwin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need mysql-devel, if it's available for cygwin, or you'll need to build mysql from source.

Your best bet is probably to just compile the MySQL client yourself in order to get the necessary headers to compile MySQLdb. See [this note](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-3.0000/INSTALL.html#windows_cygwin) on the similar Perl DB driver.

Answer (score 4):

How I did it:

First I installed [`apt-cyg`](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg). With that:

```
# apt-cyg install gcc            # older name
apt-cyg install gcc-core         # as of 2015
apt-cyg install python-setuptools
easy_install pip
pip install -U mysql-python
```

Comment: This got me a lot further. Now I'm stuck with some `gcc` compiling issues. http://stackoverflow.com/q/32969715/1245190

Answer (score 3):

First, install apt-cyg:

```
lynx -source rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg > apt-cyg`
install apt-cyg /bin
```

Now, use apt-cyg to install mysql-devel:

```
apt-cyg install libmysqlclient-devel
```

Answer (score 2):

After building MySQL using the instructions above, you'll need to do the following to build and install MySQLdb:

1. Download the Python 'setuptools' package [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#files) (example: setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg). You'll need this to run setup.py which comes with MySQL-python.
2. Install setuptools using the instructions on the same page (you just run it as if it was a shell script).
3. Download MySQL-python [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) (example: MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz).
4. Expand the archive and you'll find installation instructions in the README file.
5. Build and install MySQL-python using the instructions in the README file.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I found that when installing MySQL-python (python setup.py install) I got some permission errors, in this case you just need to open up permissions recursively on the install folder (chmod -R 755) and it will install correctly

Answer (score 2):

Got the same error after trying  `pip install mysql-python`. I have Win7 x64 + Cygwin x86 2.830 + Django 1.5.5 + Python 2.7.

So I ran Cygwin setup and downloaded the `libmysqlclient-devel`: MySQL database client library (development) and that did it!!

Answer (score 1):

I followed the directions on [this comment](http://phaseshiftllc.com/archives/2008/10/26/installing-mysql-gem-on-windows-cygwin-for-rails#comment-86) to get MySQL installed on Cygwin.  I had to use version 5.1.35, which can be downloaded from [here](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php?p=mysql-5.1&o=other), as the latest (5.1.41) failed to build.

Here is the command line I used:

./configure –without-libedit –without-readline –without-server CFLAGS=-O2`