# gcc failed with install Python MySQL libraries on Cygwin

Tags: mysql, gcc, cygwin, pip, easy-install

I want to install either `oursql` or `MySQLdb` on a Cygwin box. ([Pywikibot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot) can work with either.)
Unfortunately both `easy_install` as well as `pip` fail at installing both.

`easy_install-2.7 oursql`

```
Searching for oursql
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/oursql/
Reading http://launchpad.net/oursql
Best match: oursql 0.9.3.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/o/oursql/oursql-0.9.3.1.zip#md5=ad599ea2d95fc695df7195e9801b45c2
Processing oursql-0.9.3.1.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-kA8kUA/oursql-0.9.3.1/setup.cfg
Running oursql-0.9.3.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-kA8kUA/oursql-0.9.3.1/egg-dist-tmp-Jh5tJ1
cython not found, using previously-cython'd .c file.
mysql_config --cflags
In file included from oursqlx/oursql.c:235:0:
oursqlx/compat.h:13:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
 #include "mysql.h"
                   ^
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

`easy_install-2.7 mysql-python`

```
Searching for mysql-python
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/mysql-python/
Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.5
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip#md5=654f75b302db6ed8dc5a898c625e030c
Processing MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-JwMXUV/MySQL-python-1.2.5/setup.cfg
Running MySQL-python-1.2.5/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-JwMXUV/MySQL-python-1.2.5/egg-dist-tmp-jjPy0m
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' terminated by signal 11
```

I haven't done much `gcc` fixing in the past decade so I'm not sure how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this may help you: [Windows GCC (MinGW) binaries for Python developers](https://github.com/develersrl/gccwinbinaries)